# finding the average frequency of square wave that varies slightly using python

Tags: python, frequency

fairly new to data science in python, looking for some help. If I have an array of ones and zeros, which is roughly say 1000 elements zero then 1000 elements one and so on, and an array of time data corresponding to the ones and zeros in ms. How would i calculate the average frequency of the pulses using python? but where the data isnt precise. for example maybe the data is one for 900 elements then zero for 1100, the pulses vary a little in length. The pulses also aren't strictly ones and zeros, for ones the majority of values are one but some are zero. and same with zero pulses, the majority are zero but some are one. Thanks for any help you can offer, its greatly appreciated

Comment: fft -> abs -> times frequency -> sum -> divide by sum of abs. That's the definition of the average frequency. You could also get a median frequency by: fft -> cumsum -> divide by last element -> search for indices of value closest to 1/2 -> feed indices into frequency array -> interpolate.

Comment: Which part of this is giving you trouble? Are you asking how to compute average frequency in the abstract, or are you asking for someone to write python code for you?

Comment: Ya in the abstract, example code is certainly nice but any help is appreciated. I didn't know the steps to approach a problem like this, but Sean Lake's given me the keywords for the workflow which gives me something to google from. Just trying to wrap my head around it now

Comment: Correction: fft -> abs squared. Abs gives amplitude, you probably want the power weighted average frequency, not amplitude weighted. Median frequency would also require an abs or abs squared (shouldn't matter which, in that case).

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm getting somewhere here, appreciate the help